# light version of pages for facebook

Tags: web-crawler, facebook-social-plugins

We have a site with 10M product pages with fb like buttons and fb comments.

Facebook in turn seem to visit us by 69.171.228.x and 69.171.229.x with computers seemingly oblivious to each other. This causes traffic peaks which are hard to digest and sometimes we restort to simply blocking the fb ip:s if the site has slowed down.

I wonder, we use the opengraph meta tags to present title, images etc to facebook. Is it ok if we do a light version of the pages for facebookexternalhit, basically only with that data?

Answer (score 1):

I've set up dedicated machines that receive requests only from Facebook bots.  It requires app-layer inspection (dispatching on User-Agent), but it's a small price to pay to maintain responsiveness on your primary site.  Depending on your load balancer, it should be fairly easy to set up a dedicated pool.  If you're using cloud servers or virtual machines, you could throw up instances in a couple hours and have them in production as soon as your change management process permits.  You can also max out caching in this pool to spare load on external data sources, reduce logging, etc.

I had one of the featured sites at launch, and it was a disaster.  However, you can reach out to FB engineers and they're actually interested in helping out.  We were able to negotiate a modification to their polling interval.  This reduced session creation on our site until we could add a servlet filter to allow sessionless requests (we were using ATG Dynamo) until we could rack the hardware for the pool described above.  You may be able to do the same.

I think either of these options are better than munging your codebase, because Facebook will change their crawler activity without warning you.  At some point, such a change may render your "lightweght" page useless.

Answer (score 0):

What light version of page do you mean?

Basically facebook visit the resource using URL defined in your opengraph meta tags, which should be at moment URL to images if I am correct. I don't think they will visit your product page which aims to be presented to human kind. Also it will cache the result and should not trigger traffic when the second user view that image from facebook. It might be a good idea to host your image resources visited by facebook on another node to reduce the load of your main web server

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit unclear. I meant instead of the full fledged page with recommendations and whatnot, I'll save both me and fb both bandwidth and cpu by just delivering the og tags, basically:

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Stock Video Footage: dog</title>
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/000800083_prev_264.mov" />
...